# Make my website partially transparent to show desktop behind the browser

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, web, browser, cross-browser

I have a web application, made in .Net MVC and I am looking into whether if it's possible or not to make the browser transparent(partially) when somebody visits that page.

There is some content that I want to show as a transparent overlay on the application that might be running behind the browser.

I know that there are some browser plugins/extensions that can achieve that, but my requirement is to do it within or somehow through my webpage.

Is there any generic or browser specific API available for this?
Is it even achievable?

Note: I am emphasizing that I am talking about an actual browser here and not a Webbrowser control.

Comment: @Dimitri Neha wants to see their desktop through the browser

Comment: https://electronjs.org/apps/glass-browser